# What happens when a process enters a semaphore (critical section) and sleeps?

Tags: c, linux, semaphore, critical-section

As per my understanding, when a process enters a critical section, no other process can simultaneously enter. But i see, by a program, that it is not.

I create Process A, and child Process B.
Child enters critical section, and sleeps, meanwhile i am surprised to see that parent too enters critical section, while child sleeps. How is it possible? 2 processes simultaneously at critical section?

```
enter code here
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

sem_t sem;
int shared=0;
int pid;

void func()
{
 sem_trywait(&sem);
 if(pid==0)printf("Child entered\n");
 else if(pid>0)printf("Parent entered\n");
 sleep(2);
 shared++;
 sem_post(&sem);
 if(pid==0)printf("Child exited\n");
 else if(pid>0)printf("Parent exited\n");
}

int main()
{
 pid=fork();
 sem_init(&sem,1,0);
 if(pid==0){
  printf("In child\n");
  func();
 }
 else {
 func();
}
}
Output:
 [root@dhcppc0 semaphore]# gcc semaphore1.c -lrt
 [root@dhcppc0 semaphore]# ./a.out
  In child
  Child entered
  Parent entered

  <pause 2 secs>

  Child exited
  Parent exited
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a semaphore to work across processes, it needs to **reside in shared memory** and to be initialized with `pshared==1` - You're not putting the semaphore in shared memory. Look up e.g. `shm_open` or `mmap`.

You should also initialize the semaphore before you `fork()` - initializing a sempahore twice doesn't work. Also use `sem_wait` rather than `sem_trywait` as you seem to want to block on the semaphore. If you want `sem_trywait` at least check if the `try` part succeeded.

EDIT: Corrected source.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

sem_t * sem; /* MODIFIED: We want a semaphore in shared memory, using a pointer instead */
int shared=0;
int pid;

void func()
{
 sem_wait(sem); /* MODIFIED &sem to sem */
 if(pid==0)printf("Child entered\n");
 else if(pid>0)printf("Parent entered\n");
 sleep(2);
 shared++;
 sem_post(sem); /* MODIFIED &sem to sem */
 if(pid==0)printf("Child exited\n");
 else if(pid>0)printf("Parent exited\n");
}

int main()
{
  /* MODIFIED: Put semaphore in shared memory */
  sem = mmap(0, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
 /* MODIFIED: Initial count of 1, so that a sem_wait will succeed */
 sem_init(sem,1,1);
 /* MODIFIED: fork() after sem_init() */
 pid=fork();
 if(pid==0){
  printf("In child\n");
  func();
 }
 else {
 func();
}
}
```

Comment: @Erik:If i use, sem_wait( ) the program infinitely waits, once the child enters critical section.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Yes, you need to give the semaphore an initial count. See updated answer.

Comment: @Erik: Shared memory is needed in case both processes are independent and needs to co-operate (IPC), but in case of parent-child, the child shares, parent's code. So do you still say, shared memory is required in this case?

Comment: @Erik: I have given the semaphore count, sem_init(&sem,1,0); the third parameter initializes the semaphore value to "0", is this what you are saying?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Yes. When you fork, initially everything's shared, but marked copy-on-write. As soon as you modify something in one process, the child and parent will have different copies of that something.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: `sem_init(&sem, 1, 1);` sets the initial value to 1, so the first sem_wait will succeed and decrement the value to 0.

Comment: Using `sem_open` would be a lot easier than doing your own `shm_open` and `mmap`. That's the whole point of `sem_open`...

Comment: @R: It'd also change the semaphore from unnamed to named

Answer (score 2):

And check the return values of the sem_* functions! From the man page:

> The sem_trywait() function shall lock
>   the semaphore referenced by sem only
>   if the semaphore is currently not
>   locked; that is, if the semaphore
>   value is currently positive.
>   Otherwise, it shall not lock the
>   semaphore.

So if you don't check what it returns, you don't know if you've locked anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using sem_trywait function,then you should check the value returned by this call so as to ensure sysnchronization...

Can refer  [this](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/sem_trywait/)  for more help....

Hope this helps...